# Adding an Options Page to a Plugin

Tags: plugins, php

The first set of code adds a menu item to the sidebar. I'm attempting to add an options page (the type which shows up as a sub-page) under this. I tried to do so with the second code... but this isn't working.

How do I add an options page under a plugin's menu?

```
// Add menu page in sidebar
function admin_menu_wlseo() {
  add_menu_page('SEO', 'SEO', 'manage_options', 'wlseo', 'options_page_wlseo');
}

// Add options page in sidebar
function admin_stuff_wlseo() {
  add_options_page('Stuff', 'Stuff', 'manage_options', 'wlseo-stuff', 'options_page_wlseo');
}
```

Comment: Do you reaaaallly need a top level menu item?  Those should be reserved for really high level options like an e-commerce plugin or something.  I bet you'd be just fine with something under tools.  That said, add_options_page adds a link under the Settings menu, use add_submenu_page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AndrettiMilas, If you really need a top level menu item (which is not encouraged), you should use `add_submenu_page`instead of `add_options_page`. Please refer to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) for the required parameters.

You could add the submenu like:

`add_submenu_page( 'wlseo', 'Submenu 1', 'Submenu 1', 'manage_options', 'wlseo-submenu-1')`;

Comment: I'm trying to figured out where to paste this...

Comment: Uh... Just replace your `add_options_page` with it.

Comment: I had it in the wrong order. Should have been combined.